# HTML Tables: re-using additional width for multi-column layout

Tags: html, css, html-table

Say I have an HTML table like

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Count</th>
      <th>Year</th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Apple</td>
      <td>10000</td>
      <td>1980</td>
      <td><button>...</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Banana</td>
      <td>11000</td>
      <td>1990</td>
      <td><button>...</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Cherry</td>
      <td>12000</td>
      <td>2000</td>
      <td><button>...</button></td>
    </tr>
    <!-- and now lots more of such records -->
  </tbody>
</table>
```

As the needed width of the table is rather small, I'd like the table to re-use the additional width by repeating it's structure horizontally. So the result should be something like:

```
Name    Count   Year        Name    Count   Year        Name    Count   Year
Apple   10000   1980        Date    13000   1994        Kiwi    16000   1984
Banana  11000   1981        Fig     14000   1999        Lemon   17000   1985
Cherry  12000   2011        Grape   15000   1965        Mango   18000   1999
```

The behavior should dynamically adjust to the width of the parent container. So if there's width only for one full row, it should show the usual table behavior, if there's space for 3, like above and so on.

Now the only thing I've found is to use something like this:

```
@media (min-width: 1000px) {
    table {
      column-count: 2;
      display: block;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 1400px) {
    table {
      column-count: 3;
      display: block;
    }
}
```

But this has multiple problems:

- it does not work on Firefox
- I hard-code widths
- sometimes a row will be split visually: the top half at the bottom of one column, the bottom half at the top of the next column
- the header is not repeated horizontally

Any idea how to achieve what I need? Lots of Googling found nothing much. (But that may also be because it's hard for me to come up with proper search terms - 'multi column' in the context of 'table' mostly leads to the obvious instead of what I mean.)
Of the mentioned issues, the one with the graphical split of rows is the killer one.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/4370109/brian-tompsett-%e6%b1%a4%e8%8e%b1%e6%81%a9
Thanks for the edit. I wonder, though: what's the reason for removing my "Thanks, Max" at the end? Are there rules against being nice on SO?

Answer (score 0):

> the header is not repeated horizontally

This requires cloning of DOM elements and CSS in principle cannot generate new DOM elements so this is not possible to achieve by strictly CSS means.

So the only solution for such responsive table is to use script - to generate table content according to available width. Unfortunately.

Comment: okay, but what if I dropped the requirement of the header repeating?